# How to handle UnicodeEncodeError in python script?

Tags: python, unicode, wmi

I have a python script from which I am generating list of softwares installed on my machine. Let the name of this script be 'install.py' - it looks as below:

```
import wmi
w = wmi.WMI()
for p in w.Win32_Product():
    if (p.Version is not None) and (p.Caption is not None):
        print  p.Caption + " & "+ p.Version + "\\\\"
        print "\hline"
```

Now I am actually writting the output of this script into a output.tex file by executing it from some another script say "output_file.py", looks as below:

```
with open("D:/output.tex", "w+") as output:
    process = sp.call(["python", "D:/install.py"], stdout=output)
```

So when the above piece is executed I do get output in "output.tex" but along with error as :

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf1' in position 43:
ordinal not in range(128)
```

So, actually don't get details of all software on my system. So what shall I do to remove this error in my script. Kindly help.

Comment: You could try to use `from __future__ import unicode_literals` at the beginning of your python script. Or you could try to open the file with unicode encoding. See https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Answer (score 0):

The immediate issue is that Python 2 uses `ascii` encoding (`sys.getdefaultencoding()`) when `sys.stdout` is redirected. You could override it with `PYTHONIOENCODING` envvar:

```
call([sys.executable, os.path.join(script_dir, 'install.py')], stdout=file,
     env=dict(os.environ, PYTHONIOENCODING='utf-8'))
```

It would be enough on *nix system but Windows may interfere with passing bytes between `install.py` and the file (e.g., [the pipe `|` is broken for binary content in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33959798/4279)).

To workaround it, you could pass the filename as the command-line parameter to `install.py` and write to the file instead of printing to `sys.stdout` there.

The right solution is to put the necessary functionality into a function and [**import the module** instead of running it as a subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30076185/4279). You can use `multiprocessing` if you want to run the code in a different process as [shown in the link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30076185/4279).